# React how to set component id to be able to use document.getElementById()

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have read a few questions, and I thought that just setting the id like the following should work:

```
<MyComponent id="myId"/>
```

But when I call `document.getElementById()` on the id, I get `null` and when I inspect the page, the component has an empty id.

What am I missing?

Comment: You can set id in your `MyComponent` component's root element in `render` function and call `document.getElementById()` for that element. `MyComponent` itself is not a valid HTML element but a React component/function/class so it will not be available in DOM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Lekhnath mentioned your `MyComponent` root elements id can be used to access the component. Something like below where you can access element with "componentId":

```
class MyComponent extends Component{
  render(){
  return <div id="componentId">
             ...your child component details here
         </div>
  }
}
```